# Spring Retry: method annotated with @Recover not being called

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, spring-retry

I am testing a spring retry, but it seems the recover is not being called. Tried to get it work but it seems exhaustive. I passed to @Recover no argument, Throwable, Exception. Changed retry dependency version, and it seems it is included with aop for spring boot and removed it. Kept getting recover is not being call with the following exception messege.

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.retry.ExhaustedRetryException: Cannot locate
> recovery method; nested exception is java.lang.ArithmeticException: /
> by zero] with root cause

Any help would be much appreciated

The code i have looks like below.

Configuration class

```
package hello;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.EnableRetry;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {

            System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by `Spring Boot:");`

            String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
            Arrays.sort(beanNames);
            for (String beanName : beanNames) {
                System.out.println(beanName);
            }

        };
    }

}
```

Rest Controller class;

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Backoff;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        String result = service.getInfo();
        return result;
    }

}
```

Service class is ;

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Backoff;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Recover;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SomeService {

    @Retryable(value = ArithmeticException.class, maxAttempts = 3, `backoff = @Backoff(delay = 3000))`
    public String getInfo() {
        System.out.println("How many time will this be printed?");
        return "Hello" + 4/0;
    }

    @Recover
    public void helpHere(ArithmeticException cause) {
        System.out.println(cause);
        System.out.println("Recovery place!");
    }
}
```

This is my dependencies list

```xml
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- tag::actuator[] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end::actuator[] -->
    <!-- tag::tests[] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end::tests[] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

With try-catch and variety of arguments

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    @Retryable(value = {ArithmeticException.class}, maxAttempts = 3, `backoff = @Backoff(delay = 3000))`
    public String getInfo() {
        try {
            System.out.println("How many time will this be printed?");
            return "Hello" + 4/0;
        } catch(ArithmeticException ex) {
            System.out.println("In the arthemetic Exception");
            throw new ArithmeticException();
        }   
    }

    @Recover
    public void helpHere(ArithmeticException cause) {
        System.out.println(cause);
        System.out.println("Recovery place! ArithmeticException");
    }

    @Recover
    public void helpHere(Exception cause ) {
        System.out.println(cause);
        System.out.println("Recovery place! Exception");
    }

    @Recover
    public void helpHere(Throwable cause) {
        System.out.println(cause);
        System.out.println("Recovery place! Exception");
    }

    @Recover
    public void helpHere() {
        System.out.println("Recovery place! Exception");
    }
}
```

Screen shot of the console

[image]

Comment: why do you need to have two `@Recover` in two  different classes ?

Comment: I made a mistake when copy pasting. Both are actually the same class. Editing...one of them should be controller class

Comment: will it works if you remove ArithmeticException.class?

Comment: No It does not. I Tried to with different  argument but none worked

Comment: remove   `System.out.println(cause);` and see

Comment: also remove `{}` between `ArithmeticException.class`.

Comment: Ok I will try it

Comment: Did not help at all. It seems this @Recover thing is not hand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `try-catch` to handle it. Here the example

```
@Retryable(value = ArithmeticException.class, maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 3000))
    public String getInfo() {
        try {
            System.out.println("How many time will this be printed?");
            return "Hello" + 4 / 0;
        } catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
            // will be retried
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

`throw ex;` is a must as it is telling Spring to apply retry handling. 
With `@Recover` we define a separate recovery method for `ArithmeticException`. This allows us to run special recovery code when a retryable method fails with `ArithmeticException`.

You may refer more on [How to handle retry with Spring-Retry ?](https://www.tuturself.com/posts/view?menuId=3&postId=1145)

**Edit**

Based on the latest exception,try provide version for spring-retry

```
 <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: This Would be a better choice, Since I was not able to get the recover working. The only concern I have is, I just need to get some logic to be do if exception is thrwon. In try catch if the retry goes for 3 times, it will go in the catch the same number of time. Thanks for the option

Comment: Is this what you need ?

Comment: Kind of , but when exception occurs and it it retries 3 times, I just want to have one recover method when I do something else. in this case it goes 3 time but still works fine.

Comment: For Instance if database call fails(After 3 retrial calls with @retrable) and I could not get the input, I need to return some dummy data, just one time only. I was thinking the recover would be better.

Comment: You can have your others logic in `@Recovery`. Once it retries 3 times, it will call recover method . The recover method will only call one time.

Comment: Yes, that was what i was hoping. unfortunately methods annotated with @Recover does not work at all

Comment: These two lines  `System.out.println(cause);
        System.out.println("Recovery place!");` not printing even though you have tried  my answer ?

Comment: No! they are not.I have out put like this 
`How many time will this be printed?
printed message form catch`

`How many time will this be printed?
printed message form catch`

`How many time will this be printed?
printed message form catch`

Actually I reduced the retry into 3 times

Comment: check my answer again

Comment: _"I have out put like this 'How many time will this be printed? printed message form catch.... "_  Not sure why you need to repeat this few lines . Can you post your latest code ?

Comment: None of these helped, to trigger @Recover method

Comment: So why this answer is marked as the correct one?? @TadeleAzanaw

Comment: This is not the answer, please unmark this it is misleading

Answer (score 22):

I finally got the answer.

For a method annotated with @Recover to be invoked, it has to have the same method argument(plus the exception) and the same return type.

I tested it with different type of exception argument and methods are called if they have more specific exception type. If I have a method like this will be called than one with `Exception` argument. However, if I have multiple recover methods, only one with the more specific exception argument will be called.

```
@Recover
public String helpHere(ArithmeticException cause) {
```

Final code Example

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Backoff;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Recover;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SomeService {

@Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 3000))
public String getInfo() {
        try {
        System.out.println("How many time will this be printed?");
        return "Hello" + 4/0;
    } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("In the arthemetic Exception");
            throw new ArithmeticException();
    }   
}

@Recover
public String helpHere(ArithmeticException cause) {

        System.out.println("Recovery place! ArithmeticException");
        return "Hello";
}
@Recover
public String helpHere(Exception cause ) {

        System.out.println("Recovery place! Exception");
        return "Hello";
}

@Recover
public String helpHere() {
        System.out.println("Recovery place! Exception");
        return "Hello";
}

@Recover
public String helpHere(Throwable cause) {

        System.out.println("Recovery place! Throwable");
        return "Hello";
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the main part


For a method annotated -------with @Recover to be invoked, it has to have the same method argument(plus the exception) and the same return type-----.

Comment: You don't need the method arguments, just the exception as the paremeter worked for me. And yes, return type should be the same it seems.

Answer (score 0):

@Recover method should have the same return type and the Exception thrown as the original method for which you are writing the retry method.

> @Recover public **String** connectionException(RetryException e)
> throws **RetryException**{
> return e.getMessage(); }